# System.exit(0) causing problem with cache or memory?

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    checkSelfPermission();

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.selectimage);
    ImageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    int permssionCheck_read = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permssionCheck_write = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    int permssionCheck_internet = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET);
    if (permssionCheck_read == PERMISSION_DENIED || permssionCheck_write == PERMISSION_DENIED || permssionCheck_internet == PERMISSION_DENIED) {
        ImageButton.setEnabled(false);
        checkSelfPermission();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

checkselfpermisssion:

```
public void checkSelfPermission() {
    String temp = "";
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        temp += Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " ";
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        temp += Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE + " ";
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        temp += Manifest.permission.CAMERA + " ";
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.INTERNET) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        temp += Manifest.permission.INTERNET + " ";
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(temp) == false) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, temp.trim().split(" "), 1);
    } else {
    }
}
```

This is my code, I need to check permission. If important permissions are not allowed by user, I have to restrict the user to use app. So I ask user to allow those permissions, and restart the app by

```
System.exit(0);
```

to re-check permission. I am curious `System.exit(0);` cause problem. If I repeat (deny permission, restart app by System.exit, deny permission) like this, there might be some problem with RAM or cache?

Comment: System.exit(0); doesn't "restart" your app, it stops the jvm.

Comment: so.. there is no willing problem?

Comment: Your whole approach is wrong. In today's android you can request all the permissions you want and it will only present the user those that are not approved so you don't have to check each one individually. Also, you can get a callback with the user's respond to the request, so you can simply check in that callback if the user declined the permission, exit the app. That way when ever the user opens the app, he will be asked to give permission, as long as the user answers no, the app will be closed

Comment: just use finish to finish the current activity

Comment: Just look at the documentation of requestPermissions, to see that you can actually input an entire array of permissions to request: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the documentation of requestPermissions, to see that you can actually input an entire array of permissions to request: [https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int))

Just do:

```
String[] permissions = new String[] {
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
    Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
};
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, 3322 /* your custom request code */);
```